# How to correct Hover css effect tremble/shaking?

Tags: html, css

I made an hover effect in my website that references an image that is the original image in 65% of opacity. The problem is, and this only happens one time, only the first time i hover it everything shakes/tremble a bit, but then everything starts working just fine. Perhaps something missing in my hover code? Can you see what's wrong?

Thanks for the help :)

The css code I'm using:

```
#rebface
{

content:url("http://static.tumblr.com/g1c47pc/Td2n783c4/nface.png");  
position:relative;    
left:8%;
margin-left:20px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rebface:hover {
content:url("http://static.tumblr.com/g1c47pc/alcn783j0/nface_65.png"); 
transition: 0.5s linear;
position:relative;    

  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px; display:flex;">    

        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={Permalink}"><div id="rebface"></div></a>

</div>
```

**You can see it here:**  (This website only works in chrome/safari for now)

http://testedesignfranjas.tumblr.com/post/87336302788/blend-food-culture-magazine-concepcao-de

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. What element is 'shaking'?

Comment: I checked the facebook icon on your site and its working fine using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m. 
Well I guess you mean the short time it needs to load the additional background image. 
I'll post a answer shortly ;)

Comment: If it's the social icons moving a bit on hover, change the <a> tags within that div to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are swapping the images in the CSS content attribute. I'm quite sure these arent cached on page load so they are loaded when hovering what causes a short flickering.

You can simply avoid that by using `opacity` instead of another image.

```
.facebook
{
  content:url("http://static.tumblr.com/g1c47pc/jhDn7hp40/sitef_1.png");
  left:50px;
  z-index:2;  
  position:absolute; 
  top:110px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:50;
}

.facebook:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

And as a side note -- use `background` instead of adding a background image via the `content` attribute. It works for older browsers and is much more of a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have the following:

```
#rebtweet:hover{ some-styles }
#rebface:hover{ some-styles }
#rebtumb:hover{ some-styles }
#rebgplus:hover{ some-styles }
```

Each of these has one common style: `transition: 0.5s linear;`

Try removing this style. I'm not sure, but it may solve your flickering issue.

Hope this helps.